# How to fix navbar from disappearing when chrome browser is narrowed?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want the navbar lists that are placed on the right side, to be aligned below the header icon that is placed on the left side. One can toggle the navbar lists by creating a button to represent it, but I want it to simply expand under the header icon.

Also, I know that the disappearance is due to the `navbar-expand-lg` class. How should I approach fixing this? Is it possible by bootstrap? Or can it be fixed with HTML and CSS, as I don't want it to be done with javascript.

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
   <div class="container"> 
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">MADHUMITHA PRABAKARAN</a>
   </div>

   <!-- 

       <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>

   -->

   <div class="container"> 
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">About</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                   <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
               </li>
           </ul>  
       </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar{
    background: #ffffff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #cccccc;

    border-width: 2px;
    border-left-style: hidden;
    border-right-style: hidden;
    border-top-style: hidden;

    top:0;

}
 .navbar-brand {
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    color: white;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top:-10px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to use your `<a>your title</a>`as toggle and keep it display in all sizes. 
Then you just need to change `class="navbar-brand"` to `class="navbar-brand d-block"` to override the `"display:none"` of `.navbar-brand` in different sizes.
You might use following code snippet as a idea, which slightly alters from official documentation. Run it in full page and resize the window.

If you want to add any CSS styling. Try to do something like

```
<div class="navbar-brand newstyle">
```

then add `.newstyle { something here }` to your css stylesheet instead of modify the navbar-brand directly unless you pretty sure you are going to override the bootstrap css style for all `navbar-brand`s in your website.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
<div class="container-fluid d-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-toggler d-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" href="#">Navbar</a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
  <div class="collapse show navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar" aria-expanded="true">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>    
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: When the screen size <= 640px, I want the navbar to wrap under the header icon. For greater than 640px, I want the icon and navbar in same line.

Comment: you probably should check out the code snippet on different sizes which seems like what you said except the breakpoint for screen size. And bootstrap has specific breakpoint for different sizes you might want to check out(https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp). I wouldn't suggest you to come out own breakpoint.